# UIImagePickerController crashes on alloc/init

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController that i display in a popover when the user presses a button.  This functions perfectly normal in the iPad simulator, but when I try to do the same thing on an actual test device, I get an `NSRangeException` on the alloc/init line for my image picker!

```
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];//Crashes here on device
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) (kUTTypeImage), nil];
```

Here is the crash message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSOrderedSet initWithOrderedSet:range:copyItems:]: range {8, 1} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

I have determined it is that exact line by attempting to step over the line in debug mode, and stepping over that particular line is what causes the exception to be thrown.

EDIT:

I was able to make a basic project that reproduces this issue 100%, which leads me to believe this is an iOS bug, not something with my code.

1. Make a new project.  Select single view application.  Does not matter if it is storyboard or xib-based
2. Open the iPad xib/storyboard, add a roundrectbutton to the view
3. Add the following IBAction to the viewcontroller.  `pickerPopoverController` is a `__strong` ivar

   ```
   -(void)iMakeItCrash:(UIButton*)sender
   {
       UIImagePickerController* ip = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       ip.delegate = self;
       ip.allowsEditing = YES;
       ip.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
       ip.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) (kUTTypeImage), nil];

       pickerPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ip];
       [pickerPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
   }
   ```
4. Hook up this IBAction to the button's Touch Up Inside event.
5. Works on simulator, crashes on iPad

EDIT2:

Crash still happens if I try to use `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:`.  However, doesn't crash if I don't present the image picker at all...

Comment: If imagePicker is a property try self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

Comment: It is not a property, just an ivar

Comment: i think you just comment imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

Comment: @Spynet: that does not resolve the problem, I also don't know how setting a property AFTER the line that it crashes on would cause a problem

Comment: Do you check the media types available before you initialise (using `availableMediaTypesForSourceType:` or `isSourceTypeAvailable:`)?

Comment: I don't check for availability, but SavedPhotosAlbum should be available for any device

Comment: Added in `if ( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] )` around the whole section and it passes and still crashes

Comment: For the record, also making it a property did not help either

Comment: I did use your code and tested it in iPhone 4 and it worked just fine. Are you sure that something else is not causing the crash ? Your crash is also saying something about a crash in an NSOrderedSet. Are you doing something before these lines that might be crashing ?

Comment: The problem so far is only on an ipad, I am in the process of editing the answer to include repro steps.  Maybe something is messed up with my device

Comment: I think it might be an iOS bug because I get the same problem with an empty 'Saved Photos' album on any devices or even the simulator. If 'Saved Photos' isn't empty the problem doesn't happen. Checking isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace when it crashes, not just the "Terminating app due to uncaught exception...". There might be some clue in there.

Comment: @glenstorey Youre right, I just took a screenshot on the device, and the bug is no longer happening.  I think I will go report this one to apple, but even if I delete the photos, I still no longer have the bug.  Go ahead and post your comment as an answer, even though it doesn't resolve the root issue, it still fixed my problem

Comment: Cool thanks. It's nice to know someone else has hit the same problem. I'll file a bug report too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this when my app crashed on an empty 'Saved Photos' album on any of my devices, or the simulator. If Saved Photos has photos in it the bug doesn't happen. It is easy to replicate if you use Reset Data and Settings on the simulator, and leave your albums empty.

I've spent ages trying to find a workaround but I haven't been able to. I think filing an iOS bug report is a real good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem once and fixed with the bellow codes:

```
-(IBAction)actionOpenPhotoLibrary:(id)sender
{
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]){
    return;
}

if ([popover isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    return;
}

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]autorelease];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
imagePicker.delegate = self;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){

    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];              
    popover.delegate = self;
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 460)];
    [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:(UIButton*)sender] autorelease] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = APP_THEME_COLOR;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Wish your best of luck.....